# Handling virtual money - How does elance, odesk and others do it?

Tags: sql, transactions, nosql, currency

I was wondering how do elance, odesk and similar sites handle money...

When you deposit the money to that site does the money go to their bank account and you get virtual money (attached to your user entity in database or something)? And how do moeny transfers between users work when someone completes a job?

Do you necesarily need database transactions to do this kind of stuff so it doesn't fail or get abused?
And, can it be done with No SQL solutions since they don't support transactions?

The way I see it the problem of withdrawing the money twice (with no transactions) can be solved by locking. You could've locked the transafer process by combined user IDs (from and to Id).

Am I on the rigth track and do I really need to use some db with transaction support for this part?

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all the world's financial accounting is done using an RBDMS (like Oracle, SQL Server, DB2 or MySQL). However, if you  want to go NoSQL you can consider a CQRS solution like CouchDB.